# How to change the starting index and have it read only to a specific row not the entire rows?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, data-analysis

I want to write a loop that would iterate through a row in excel file but i want to start at a certain index row and end at a certain row instead of iterating through the entire thing. I'm new to python and don't know the exact syntax for it thanks.

I've try looking up the n.rows function to see if there's any restrictions that I can put but I can't find any.

```
  book = 
  xlrd.open_workbook("/Users/vhim/Documents/Cases/Orders.xlsx")
  sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Summary")
  #print(sheet.col_values(1))

  i = 0
  #for col in range (sheet.ncols):
  for row in range (sheet.nrows):
        i = i+1
        print(sheet.col_values(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Pandas library, you can read the excel file skipping this first rows and also skipping last rows like:

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile("/Users/vhim/Documents/Cases/Orders.xlsx")
page_summary = pd.read_excel(xls, "Summary", skiprows = 100, nrows = 200)
```

This will read from row number 100 to row number 300, and now to iterate:

```
for row in page_summary.iterrows:
     print(row[1]['COLUMN NAME'])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) can start and stop any where you want. Use [`sheet.row`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.row) to get a specific sheet

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("temp.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Summary")

# rows 3, 4, 5, and 6
first, last = 3,6
for rowx in range(first, last+1):
    rowx_cells = sheet.row(rowx)
```

Comment: how would you do that for a number of specific rows within a column

Comment: @VathanaHim: use `cels = sheet.col(colx)` to get a sequence of cells in the column then slice the sequence for the rows you want `values = cels[first:last+1]` There are a number of ways to do it making use of [sheet methods](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd-sheet) - [`sheet.col_slice()`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.col_slice) would work.